# AWS ApiGateway define with OpenApi, how to use an Authorizer type clientCredentials

Tags: amazon-web-services, oauth-2.0, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito, aws-serverless

I deploy an ApiGateway define by OpenAPI file with AWS SAM :

```
ApiGateway:
Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
Properties:
  Description: Example API Gateway
  Name: !Ref ApiGatewayName
  StageName: !Ref ApiGatewayStageName
  OpenApiVersion: 3.0.1
  BinaryMediaTypes:
    - multipart/form-data
    - applicaton/json
  EndpointConfiguration:
    Type: REGIONAL
  Domain:
    DomainName: !Ref DomainName
    CertificateArn: !Ref ApiCertificat
    # EndpointConfiguration: REGIONAL
    Route53:
      HostedZoneId: !Ref PublicHostedZoneId
  DefinitionBody:
    'Fn::Transform':
      Name: AWS::Include
      Parameters:
        Location: !Sub s3://${S3TemplateBucket}/openapi.yaml
```

The needs is to configure SwaggerUI with correct Oauth `clientCredentials`  securitySchemes and to have the Authorizer ressource initialized in AWS ApiGateway with the use of `x-amazon-apigateway-authtype & x-amazon-apigateway-authorizer`

This following OpenAPI def is working well in SwaggerUI but it's not possible to configure Authorizer in ApiGateway other than by Oauth `type: apiKey` like the AWS documentation talks about.

> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-swagger-extensions-authorizer.html

```
paths:
    put:
      summary: hello th world
      description: helloworld
      operationId: hello
      requestBody:
        description: the word
      responses:
        ...
      security:
        - security1:
            - hello.eu/say-hello
      x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
        uri:
          Fn::Sub: arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${SayHello.Arn}/invocations
        ...
components:
  securitySchemes:
    security1: # work one SwaggerUI but could not init Authorizer in ApiGateway even if we add x-amazon-apigateway ...
      type: oauth2
      flows: 
        clientCredentials: 
          tokenUrl: https://{UserPoolDomain.Domain}.auth.eu-west-1.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/token/
          scopes:
            hello.eu/say-hello: could say hello
    security2: # work but not type of clientCredentials in SwaggerUI
      type: apiKey
      name: Authorization
      in: header
      x-amazon-apigateway-authtype: cognito_user_pools
      x-amazon-apigateway-authorizer:
        type: cognito_user_pools
        providerARNs:
          - 'arn:aws:cognito-idp:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:userpool/${UserPool}'
```

> One of the last solution would be to declare the both securitySchemes in the OpenAPI file. One for the SwaggerUI and the second for ApiGateway configuration but it's not clean and the securityScheme is doubled in SwaggerUI.